# Getting Schema validation: Incompatible types in detekt.yml in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, yaml, detekt

Any way I can fix the schema warning in `detekt.yml` I am attaching the screenshot and open to add more details

Minimum reproducible `detekt.yml` below

```yaml
build:
  maxIssues: 0
  excludeCorrectable: false
  weights:
     complexity: 2
     LongParameterList: 1
     style: 1
     comments: 1

config:
  validation: true
  warningsAsErrors: true
  # when writing own rules with new properties, exclude the property path e.g.: 'my_rule_set,.*>.*>[my_property]'
  excludes: ''

processors:
  active: true
  exclude:
    - 'DetektProgressListener'
  # - 'KtFileCountProcessor'
  # - 'PackageCountProcessor'
  # - 'ClassCountProcessor'
  # - 'FunctionCountProcessor'
  # - 'PropertyCountProcessor'
  # - 'ProjectComplexityProcessor'
  # - 'ProjectCognitiveComplexityProcessor'
  # - 'ProjectLLOCProcessor'
  # - 'ProjectCLOCProcessor'
  # - 'ProjectLOCProcessor'
  # - 'ProjectSLOCProcessor'
  # - 'LicenseHeaderLoaderExtension'

style:
  active: true
  ReturnCount:
    active: true
    max: 2
    excludedFunctions: 'equals'
    excludeLabeled: false
    excludeReturnFromLambda: true
    excludeGuardClauses: true
```

Android version: Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335, built on September 30, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay after some exploration I found out, in the `detekt` [release v1.21.0](https://github.com/detekt/detekt/releases/tag/v1.21.0) they changed all their configuration from comma-separated `string` to `array` of `string` in `detekt.yml`.

So initially it used to be `excludedFunctions: 'equals, hashCode'` now they have become `excludedFunctions: ['equals', 'hashCode']`

After `detekt` [release v1.22.0](https://github.com/detekt/detekt/releases/tag/v1.22.0), they started throwing error while building the project.